# grep option 'o' command not working

Tags: grep

I have a particular string that i want to match with the contents of my file.But I dont want the whole line.I just want the matched string.Say,my file file1.txt,has the following contents

```
My name is John
I am 22 years old
```

Now I want to return only those strings which contain 'am'.That is,I want my output to return

```
name
am
```

I read that grep -o option would help in giving this output...but when i type

```
grep -o "am" file1.txt
```

it returns Illegal option
Can somebody please help me with this...

Comment: Do you have any alias for grep in your console?

Comment: run the command with `strace` just to be sure what is being sent to `execve`.

Comment: So the other thing is, even if you _could_ do `-o` it would only match the exact part.  So in your case, you would get something like:
`am\n am`
What you will want to do (assuming you get the `-o` flag working) is something like this `grep -o "\<\w*am\w*\>" file1.txt`

Comment: But the grep -o option itself isnt working.Is there any other way of getting the matched string?

Comment: @Martin I have an alias for grep, is there a solution without deleting the alias?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed for this:

```
sed -n 's/.*\b\(\w*am\w*\)\b.*/\1/p' file.txt
name
am
```